# Simple vba command to delete a section of PowerPoint slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a large master presentation and I want a VBA UserForm to offer checkboxes for inclusion/deletion of slide sections for custom presentations.

My form is working well, but I'm not getting the syntax right to delete a section of slides based on a checkbox being unchecked upon form button click. I found very limited reference material from Microsoft.

```
If chkAutomotive = False Then
        ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Delete(1,True)
    End If
```

In this case, the Automotive section of slides is the first section and if the checkbox is unchecked, I'd like to delete the slides in that section.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the parentheses in Microsoft's syntax description are not supposed to be included. Works fine now.